# Is there a name for this vintage 3-pin connector configuration?

Tags: rf, identification, connector, radio, vintage

I am trying to find a suitable replacement for this connector for a vintage radio, but I'm not sure how to search for it or if they even sell them anymore.

Simply "3 pin male connector" isn't helping very much, and the part has no markings.

I've seen this before on an old stereo amplifier I had as well, with one vertical pin and two horizontal.

Is there a name for this particular pin layout or type of connector?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the connector's purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jones plug, 303 format, as made by Cinch (which acquired Jones in the 1940s):
https://belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/cinchconnectivitysolutions/industrialcinch/ds-ccs-ind-jones-plugs-300-series.pdf

Jones plugs are designed for use as a normal power plug: cheap, medium current, frequent insertion/removal.

Comment: Excellent! I figured there was an identification number for the pinout in a datasheet somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: They're not always used for power; I believe these were used for telephones in some parts of the world, and I've seen them used for speaker connections on old audio equipment.

Comment: Can the example shown in the picture really be used for power, unless at very low voltage?-- See its two flanges, and their direct metal connection to the two outer pins!

Comment: @terry-s That seems manually soldered to the housing.

Comment: @terry-s and this one is screwed in, not 'frequently' removed. But the Jones system was designed to handle 10A at 250V -- and probably was higher voltage before radio standards regulation specified the 250V limit

Answer (score 7):

That is a Cinch-Jones 300-Series connector, universally called a "Jones Plug".  Beau makes something similar.  Here is the Mouser version of the catalog:

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/643/ds_CCS_IND_jones_plugs_300_series-1358563.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a Jones plug to me.  Mouser, and no doubt other major distributors, carry them. (Also called "Cinch-Jones")